# How to find PV $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log \cos^2 \alpha x}{\beta^2-x^2} \, \mathrm dx=\alpha \pi$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$
I:=PV\int_0^\infty \frac{\log\left(\cos^2\left(\alpha x\right)\right)}{\beta^2-x^2} \, \mathrm dx=\alpha \pi,\qquad \alpha>0,\  \beta\in \mathbb{R}.$$
I am trying to solve this integral, I edited and added in Principle value to clarify the convergence issue that the community pointed out.  I tried to use $2\cos^2(\alpha x)=1+\cos 2\alpha x\,$ and obtained
$$
I=-\log 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{\beta^2-x^2}+\int_0^\infty \frac{\log (1+\cos 2 \alpha x)}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm dx,
$$
simplifying
$$
I=\frac{ \pi \log 2 }{2\beta}+\int_0^\infty \frac{\log (1+\cos 2 \alpha x)}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm dx
$$
but  stuck here. Note the result of the integral is independent of the parameter $\beta$. Thank you

Also for $\alpha=1$, is there a geometrical interpretation of this integral and why it is $\pi$?

Note this integral 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log \sin^2 \alpha x}{\beta^2-x^2} \,\mathrm dx=\alpha \pi-\frac{\pi^2}{2\beta},\qquad \alpha>0,\beta>0
$$
is also FASCINATING, note the constraint $\beta>0$ for this one.  I am not looking for a solution to this too obviously on the same post, it is just to interest people with another friendly integral.

Comment: Could the fact that $$\log(1+\cos(2\alpha x))=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\cos^k(2\alpha x)$$Be used? ($\cos(2\alpha x)<1\forall 2\alpha x$)

Comment: I meant $\cos(2\alpha x)\leq1$.

Comment: does this even converge?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Oh yes it converges, I saw a proof for this around 1980.  It will give your mathematica or whatever trouble though.  I also have hundreds of integral that will stump  mathematica like this.

Comment: @Integrals particularly when $x=\beta$ and $\cos (\alpha \beta) \neq 1$

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Thanks.  What do you expect to do with the $\cos^k(2\alpha x)$ term in the integral if exploit uniform convergence on the integrand, we will have something like 
$$
\sum_k \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos^k(2\alpha x)}{\beta^2-x^2}dx
$$

Comment: Integrals, what book are you getting this from? I would also like to solve these types of problems like few monsters around here.

Comment: @Integrals Reduction formulae? Tedious, yes, but helpful, perhaps?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ I added to the post too, Thanks.  It is just a constant.  THe only restrictions for convergence is $\alpha>0$ is only restriction for convergence.  I  have references for this and many kinds of these integrals if you want

Comment: @SantoshLinkha a lot of these are from growing up in math high school and at Sofia university around 1980.  We were at the international level in Bulgaria but the competition was strong.  Here are some good ones,  Demidovich- Problems in mathematical analysis, Ryzhik Integral Table, (Russian versioN), Special Functions-Wang, Special Functions- Lebedev.  Those 4 can keep you busy for now, let me know please if you wish to discuss more

Comment: @SantoshLinkha You can also try this one
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log \sin^2 \alpha x}{\beta^2-x^2} \, dx=\alpha \pi-\frac{\pi^2}{2\beta},\qquad \alpha>0,\beta>0.
$$
Note, this integral requires $\beta >0.$

Comment: thank you very much for recommendation (y)

Comment: If $\cos^2(\alpha |\beta|)\neq 1$, then the integral under consideration diverges in view of a singularity at $x=|\beta|$.

Comment: @user64494 Note the convergence required is the same as the integral for $\alpha=1,\beta=0$ I posted last week
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{-2}\log \cos^2 x\, dx=-\pi.
$$

Comment: @ Integrals : Could you kindly found the convergence of the integral under consideration in detail?

Comment: @user64494 I do not understand that question, can you re-phrase please?  Thanks

Comment: @ Integrals : Have you read my previous comment?

Comment: @user64494 Yes I replied.  can you please re-phrase your question? I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @Integrals He wants to you prove in detail that the integral converges. To be honest, I think it only converges in a principal value sense because of the singularity at $x = \beta$.

Comment: @user111187 yes thank you for clarifying.  Note, I am implicitly seeking the cases when the integral is convergent and gives a value $\alpha \pi.$  If I want to discuss convergence as the Primary concern, I will start to post  in different tags.

Comment: @Integrals Signs are not important. It depends on $\large\left\vert\,\alpha\,\right\vert$ and $\large\left\vert\,\beta\,\right\vert$.

Comment: Why does $\alpha$ need to be positive? Isn't $\cos(\alpha x) = \cos(-\alpha x)$ ?

Comment: User64494 is correct - I don't think this integral converges.  The RHS if anything is a Cauchy PV.

Comment: @RonGordon Please see solution below.   The integral converges.

Comment: @user64494 Please see solution below.

Comment: @Integrals, usual integral and Cauchy PV integral are slightly different objects. And the integral in question does not converge as improper integral sense except for some rare occurrence where the singularity is cancelled. That's what peoples said and that's why I began with the Cauchy PV.

Comment: so it was PV you calculate after all ... hehehe

Comment: If $\alpha = \frac{n \pi}{\beta}$, then the singularity at $x=\beta$ is removable.  And in that case we could drop the PV.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you for your thought and message on this PV!  And solving all of my integrals as always.  And your edit to the post.  Thank you

Comment: The integral is not really independent of $\beta$. The integral is $\frac\pi{|\beta|}$ periodic and equal to $\pi\alpha$ when $|\alpha|\lt\frac\pi{2|\beta|}$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We make use of the identity

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{2} - (x + n\pi)^{2}} = \frac{\cot(x+a) - \cot(x-a)}{2a}, \quad a > 0 \text{ and } x \in \Bbb{R}. $$

Then for $\alpha, \beta > 0$ it follows that

\begin{align*}
I := \mathrm{PV}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log\cos^{2}(\alpha x)}{\beta^{2} - x^{2}}
&= \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log\cos^{2}(\alpha x)}{\beta^{2} - x^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{2} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log\cos^{2}x}{(\alpha\beta)^{2} - x^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\log\cos^{2}x}{(\alpha\beta)^{2} - (x+n\pi)^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{2} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\alpha\beta)^{2} - (x+n\pi)^{2}} \right) \log\cos^{2}x \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{4\beta} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cot(x+\alpha\beta) - \cot(x-\alpha\beta)) \log\cos^{2}x \, dx,
\end{align*}

where interchanging the order of integration and summation is justified by Tonelli's theorem applied to the summation over large indices $n$. Then

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{1}{4\beta} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cot(x+\alpha\beta) - \cot(x-\alpha\beta)) \log\cos^{2}x \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\beta} \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cot(x+\alpha\beta) - \cot(x-\alpha\beta)) \log\left|2\cos x\right| \, dx \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Here, we exploited the following identity to derive (1).

$$ \mathrm{PV} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cot(x+a) \, dx = 0 \quad \forall a \in \Bbb{R}. $$

Now with the substitution $z = e^{2ix}$ and $\omega = e^{2i\alpha\beta}$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{1}{2\beta} \Re \mathrm{PV} \int_{|z|=1} \left( \frac{\bar{\omega}}{z - \bar{\omega}} - \frac{\omega}{z - \omega} \right) \log(1 + z) \, \frac{dz}{z}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Now consider the following unit circular contour $C$ with two $\epsilon$-indents $\gamma_{\omega,\epsilon}$ and $\gamma_{\bar{\omega},\epsilon}$.

[image]

Then the integrand of (2)

$$ f(z) = \left( \frac{\bar{\omega}}{z - \bar{\omega}} - \frac{\omega}{z - \omega} \right) \frac{\log(1 + z)}{z} $$

is holomorphic inside $C$ (since the only possible singularity at $z = 0$ is removable) and has only logarithmic singularity at $z = -1$. So we have

$$ \oint_{C} f(z) \, dz = 0. $$

This shows that

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{1}{2\beta} \Re \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left( \int_{-\gamma_{\omega,\epsilon}} f(z) \, dz + \int_{-\gamma_{\bar{\omega},\epsilon}} f(z) \, dz \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\beta} \Re \left( \pi i \mathrm{Res}_{z=\omega} f(z) + \pi i \mathrm{Res}_{z=\bar{\omega}} f(z) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\beta} \Re \left( - \pi i \log(1 + \omega) + \pi i \log(1 + \bar{\omega}) \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\beta} \arg(1 + \omega)
 = \frac{\pi}{\beta} \arctan(\tan (\alpha \beta)).
\end{align*}

In particular, if $\alpha\beta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ then we have

$$ I = \pi \alpha. $$

But due to the periodicity of $\arg$ function, this function draws a scaled saw-tooth function for $\alpha > 0$. Of course, $I$ is an *even* function of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so the final result is obtained by even extension of this saw-tooth function.

Comment: +1 Thank you for providing proof to this problem.  How did you draw your contour?  Do you use mathematica to do so?

Comment: Also, do you have any proof or reference for this, $a>0, x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^{2} - (x + n\pi)^{2}} = \frac{\cot(x+a) - \cot(x-a)}{2a}.
$$
Thanks again for your solution

Comment: @Integrals, I use Mathematica, so basically I use some calculation to create a figure. For the series, you can first apply partial fraction decomposition and then apply the [*partial fraction decomposition* formula for tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions_in_complex_analysis#Example).

Comment: Okay great thanks you.  I will look into the contour drawing.

Comment: @RandomVariable That sounds much simpler. Actually, what I did in the first step is to wind the upper-half plane $\Bbb{H}$ into the unit disc $\Bbb{D}$, so the theoretically two approaches are almost equivalent. Still, your idea leads to a much simpler solution. (Actually what I intended first is to use some real-analysis techniques... the first part is just a trace of this unsuccessful approach.)

Comment: May I ask you to explain this step for me please
\begin{align}
\frac{\alpha}{2}PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log\cos^2x}{(\alpha\beta)^2-x^2}dx
&=\frac{\alpha}{2}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}PV\int_{\Large-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\log \cos^2{x}}{(\alpha\beta)^2 - (x+n\pi)^2}}dx
\end{align}
Thanks.

Comment: @AchalGautam You can divide the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$ into $\cdots \cup [-3\pi/2, -\pi/2] \cup [-\pi/2, \pi/2] \cup [\pi/2, 3\pi/2] \cup \cdots$. Then your integral splits as the sum of integrals on these  subintervals, and by translation it is finally written as the sum as in the identity.

Answer (score 23):

Consider the function $$ f(z) = \frac{\log(1+e^{2i \alpha z})}{z^{2}-\beta^{2}} \ , \ (\alpha,\beta >0)$$

which is well-defined on the complex plane if we omit the real axis and restrict $z$ to the upper half-plane while defining $\log (1+e^{2iaz})$ to be $\log(2)$ just above the origin.

Notice that  $$\text{Re} \big( f(x) \big) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\log(2+2 \cos 2 \alpha x)}{x^{2}-\beta^{2}} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\log \big(4 \cos^{2} ( \alpha x) \big)}{x^{2}-\beta^{2}}.$$

Now integrate around a contour that consists of the line segment just above the line segment $[-R,R]$ (with half-circle indentations of radius $r$ around the branch points at $z= \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2 \alpha}$ and the simple poles at $z = \pm \beta$) and the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$.

Along the upper half of $|z|=R$, $\log(1+e^{2iaz}) \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$. So the integral clearly vanishes along there as $R \to \infty$.

And since $\lim_{z \to \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2 \alpha}}\left(z- \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2 \alpha} \right) f(z) = 0$, the contributions from the indentations around the branch points vanish as $r \to 0$.

So we have

$$\begin{align}  \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \left(4 \cos^{2}( \alpha x)\right)}{\beta^{2}-x^{2}} \ dx &= -2 \ \text{Re} \ \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1+e^{2i \alpha x})}{x^{2}-\beta^{2}} \ dx \\ &= -2 \ \text{Re} \Big( i \pi \ \text{Res}[f(z),\beta)] + i \pi \ \text{Res}[f(z),-\beta)]\Big) \\ &= - 2 \ \text{Re} \ i \pi  \Big(\frac{\log(1+e^{2i \alpha \beta})}{2 \beta} + \frac{\log(1+e^{-2i \alpha \beta})}{-2 \beta} \Big) \\ &= \frac{2\pi}{\beta} \left[\arctan\Big(\frac{\sin 2 \alpha \beta}{1+\cos 2 \alpha \beta}\Big) \right] \\ &= \frac{2 \pi}{\beta} \arctan \left(\tan ( \alpha \beta) \right) , \end{align}$$

which implies

$$ \log(4) \ \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\beta^{2}-x^{2}} \ dx + \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \cos^{2}(\alpha x)}{\beta^{2}-x^{2}} \ dx = \frac{2 \pi}{\beta} \arctan \left( \tan (\alpha \beta) \right).$$

But $$\text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\beta^{2}-x^{2}} \ dx =0$$

since the residues at $\pm \beta$ cancel each other.

Therefore,

$$ \text{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log \cos^{2}(\alpha x)}{\beta^{2}-x^{2}} \ dx =  \frac{\pi}{\beta} \arctan \left(\tan (\alpha \beta) \right).$$

And if $\alpha \beta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $$ \text{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log \cos^{2}(\alpha x)}{\beta^{2}-x^{2}} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{\beta} \left(\alpha \beta \right) =\pi \alpha.$$

Comment: whoever down votes random variable needs to reevaluate what they think they know about mathematics.  He solves $\approx$ every integral I post!!!!

Comment: I can't tell, are you switching the order of taking the logarithm and taking the real part in the beginning? 

If so, how is this justified? Take for example $z = \pi/4 - i\log(\sqrt{2}).$ Then $f(z)=1+e^{iz} = 2+i$ which has real part $2$. Hence $\log(\mathscr{R}(f))=\log(2)$. 

However, $\log(f(z)) = \log|2+i| + i \arg(2+i) = \log(\sqrt{5}) + i \arctan(1/2).$ This has real part $\log(\sqrt{5})$ which is not $\log(2).$

Comment: @glowsticc  $$ \log(1+e^{2iax}) = \log(1+\cos 2ax + i \sin 2ax)$$

$$ = \log |1+\cos 2ax  + i \sin 2ax| + i \arg( 1+ \cos 2ax +i \sin 2ax )$$

$$ = \log \left( \sqrt{1+2 \cos 2ax + \cos^{2}(2ax) + \sin^{2}(2ax)} \right) + i \arctan \left( \frac{\sin 2ax}{1 + \cos 2ax} \right) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \log(2+ 2 \cos 2ax) + i \arctan \left( \frac{\sin 2ax}{1 + \cos 2ax} \right)$$

Then I'm just extracting the real part.

Comment: +1. The result is so simple that it should be some way to get it in an elementary way. I guess so. I couldn't imagine any simple way. Nice answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks. This was sort of a simplification of sos440's approach. I don't know of any other way to approach it.

Answer (score 13):

Let us use the contour $\gamma$ which is the limit as $R\to\infty$ and $r\to0$ of
$$
[-R,-\beta-r]\cup-\beta+re^{i[\pi,0]}\cup[-\beta+r,\beta-r]\cup\beta+re^{i[\pi,0]}\cup[\beta+r,R]\cup Re^{i[0,\pi]}
$$

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

to compute
$$
\begin{align}
&PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i\alpha x}}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_\gamma\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{\beta^2-z^2}\mathrm{d}z+\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-\beta}\left(\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{\beta^2-z^2}\right)+\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\beta}\left(\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{\beta^2-z^2}\right)\\
&=0+\pi i\frac{e^{-i\alpha\beta}}{2\beta}-\pi i\frac{e^{i\alpha\beta}}{2\beta}\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi\beta\sin(\alpha\beta)
\end{align}
$$
where $\alpha\ge0$ (needed so that the integral vanishes along the large arc); however, the principal value integral is even in $\alpha$.

Setting $\alpha=0$ gives
$$
PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=0
$$

---

Now we can use that
$$
\log\left(\cos^2(\alpha x)\right)=-2\log(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\cos(2k\alpha x)
$$
to get, for $\alpha\ge0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(\cos^2(\alpha x)\right)}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\log\left(\cos^2(\alpha x)\right)}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi\beta\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\sin(2k\alpha\beta)\\
&=\frac\pi\beta\frac1{2i}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\left(e^{2ik\alpha\beta}-e^{-2ik\alpha\beta}\right)\\
&=\frac\pi\beta\frac1{2i}\left(\log\left(1+e^{2i\alpha\beta}\right)-\log\left(1+e^{-2i\alpha\beta}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

---

Note that
$$
\theta(\alpha,\beta)=\frac\pi\beta\frac1{2i}\left(\log\left(1+e^{2i\alpha\beta}\right)-\log\left(1+e^{-2i\alpha\beta}\right)\right)
$$
is an odd function of $\alpha$ with a period of $\frac\pi{|\beta|}$ and equals $\pi\alpha$ for $|\alpha|\lt\frac\pi{2|\beta|}$. Furthermore, in general,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(\cos^2(\alpha x)\right)}{\beta^2-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\theta(|\alpha|,\beta)
$$
and $\theta(|\alpha|,\beta)=\pi|\alpha|$ for $|\alpha|\le\frac\pi{2|\beta|}$.

Thus, the integral is not totally independent of $\beta$.

Comment: Sir Robjohn.  Thank you for another method to solving this problem!